# Why we have backslash for DOS and slash for linux and URL?

Tags: escaping, backslash, slash

I use both windows and Linux and often I got confused when I use command lines...

1>MS-DOS use **backslash** like `C:\Documents and Settings\user_name\Desktop\`

2>Linux use **slash** like `/usr/lib`

3>URL seems to use **slash** like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

4>C++/C programmer often use **backslash** as the escape character like `\n or \t or \"`

Item 1-3 can be confusing plus the effect of item 4.
I am wondering why MS-DOS doesn't use (forward) slash just as everything else, and then we can only use the special backslash as the escape character.

Comment: This is not a question for SO

Comment: The author (or purchaser) of DOS probably wanted to it to look different than the popular operating systems of the time (UNIX).

Comment: For compatibility with DOS 1.0. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash

Comment: you can use / for windows, e.g. c:/windows/system it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered at superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes

Let me quote the gist of it:

> MS-DOS 2.0 introduced \ as the directory separator in the early 1980s. The reason / was not used is that MS-DOS 1.0 was already using / to introduce command-line options. It took this usage of / from CP/M, which took it from VMS.